# How can I guess the route helpers that are created with match in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have created a route in the `routes.rb` file like this:

```
match ':controller/:action/:id'
```

I tried invoking `add_posts_path()` and `add_post_path()` from my view and in both cases I got similar error messages like this one:

```
undefined method `add_post_path' for ...
```

I have tried declaring my match route both before and after the `resources :posts` declaration.

Are any route helpers created for such a route? I am unsure what helper methods can be used with such a match rule.

Comment: first of all: `rake routes`... it will show all the routes generated by your routes.rb.

Answer (score 1):

You can name routes with :as parameter

```
match '/foo/bar', to: 'foo#bar', as: 'foo_bar'
```

and then use foo_bar_path in your view

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

Comment: Thanks. I think this can solve my problem, although it doesn't help to solve my doubt. Are there any helpers created automatically for a route like `match ':controller/:action/:id'`?

Comment: No, i don't think so as it's a catch all route

Answer (score 0):

If you have `resources :posts`, you have a helper `new_post_path` to *add* new posts. Run `rake routes` to see your apps routes.

`add_post_path` does't follow Rails routes convention for resources and if you need it, must add a custom method:

```
resources :posts do
  get :add, :on => :collection
end
```

You can read more about this in this [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

When you define `match ':controller/:action/:id'`, you set the format of your app's urls and their params, but this do not magically will define routes helpers.

Comment: I knew about the `new_post_path`, thanks. My `add` method does something different. I am quite sure there are some helpers that are automatically created by Rails though metaprogramming, though. It's just that I am not sure how they should be called.